# displaying images contained inside individual gallery

Tags: lightbox, lightbox2

I am using a lightbox gallery and I managed to integrate it into my web site.
Please have a look at a file: https://gist.github.com/2517910
As you could see from the file I've added two galleries- each gallery has five pictures.
The current behavior is: when I click on a certain picture and when it shows up I can navigate through all 10 pictures.
What I would like is to change this behavior. That is I'd like when I click on a picture inside first gallery 5 pictures form that gallery is shown.
And when I click on a picture in the second gallery - 5 pictures from that gallery are show.
And that I can navigate through pictures inside each of the galleries without possibility to look at the other pictures from other gallery.

Comment: Both your gallery have the same id (ids must be unique). It may or not be the cause of your problem, but it's an easy fix, so try it.

Comment: mdi, thanks for your reply. I've changed id's but then in the gallery whose ID I changed lightbox gallery is not applied

Comment: Yes, you must apply it to both. I don't know if lightbox can do this, but there's no reasons it won't. Edit your message with your javascript so I can look at it.

Comment: Did you work out an answer to this issue @Dantes? I am trying to figure out how to separate the carousel on various galleries on a single page also.

Comment: Oh yeah, I get it now, it's got everything to do with the 'data-lightbox' attribute - not the ID attribute of the parent DIV tag. Just make sure each group/gallery of images have a unique value for 'data-lightbox'. Of course the code has probably changed heaps since this post http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/